# JS: Function is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, oop, defined

I've been trying to make somekind of a starry sky. Here's the code.
When I'm trying to load the page, the console says that `createHtmlElementFromStar`is not defined. I can't find out why.
Thanks for your answers in advance!

```
 var Star = function (x, y, look, color) {
    var _x = x;
    var _y = y;
    var _look = look;
    var _color = color;

    this.createHtmlElementFromStar = function () {
        var st = document.createElement("span");
        st.style.position = "absolute";
        st.style.left = x + "px";
        st.style.top = (y - 10) + "px";
        return st;
    };

};

var Stars = function () {
    var _stars = new Array();

    this.createStars = function (look, count) {
        var x = Math.random() * (400 - x) + x;
        var y = Math.random() * (400 - y) + y;
        var look = "";
        var color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
        _stars.push(new Star(x, y, look, color));
    };

    this.showStars = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < _stars.length; i++) {
        document.body.appendChild(createHtmlElementFromStar(_stars[i]));
        };
    };};


var stars = new Stars();
stars.createStars(1, 50, "*", 150);
stars.showStars();
```

Comment: correct `createHtmlElementFromStar` is not defined ... it's a method of `Star` object ... so `_stars[i].createHtmlElementFromStar` **is** defined - but that doesn't take an argument ... I think you'll need to revisit Javascript 101 - to know how to write javasrcipt

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it really is defined. I'm sorry for bad syntax or code, I've got a lot to learn still. I'll definitely look into js 101!

Comment: `var x = Math.random() * (400 - x) + x;` ... what do you expect x will be?

Comment: `this.createStars` accepts a look and count argument - never uses the count argument ... and you call it with 4 arguments ...!!

Comment: you'd have to have a function called `getrandomint` I guess

Comment: OK, I see now. My fault I missed it. Thanks for helping with this!